According to Catholicism, can a confession be spread over multiple sessions?
Can a confession be spread over multiple sessions, if for example it's not feasible to do it at once due to time constraints?  If so, would this be allowed for anonymous confessions or would they have to be face-to-face?

I don't believe they can be, no. If you need extra time for your confession, you should schedule a time for it.

According to Catholicism, can a confession be spread over multiple sessions?
The short answer is yes.
There are several reasons and scenarios that may make this a viable option or necessity.
Some years ago, prior to the pontificate of Pope Francis, those who had confessed to have partaking in the sin of abortion priests needed to have the local bishop to absolve the sin of abortion. In other words, priests had to get this permission from their local ordinary and schedule another time for the penitent to receive absolution.
Then there is the scenario that involves a ”general confession”. A general confession is the detailed confession of the entire life of a penitent and would generally take several cessation’s in order for the penitent to reveal all the remembered sins of an individual’s life time. This form of confession is generally practiced by religious just prior to making their religious vows of poverty, chastity and obedience.
These are only two examples of reasons why some confessions may take over more than one or two cessations.
If a priest needs guidance from a more experienced confessor to deal with a difficult case of conscience, he first must ask the permission of the penitent to discuss the matter. Even in this case, the priest must keep the identity of the person secret.
Please bear in mind that certain sins are reserved to the Holy See before absolution may be administered.
These confessions may be anonymous or face to face, but in whatever circumstances, the priest must keep the identity of the penitent secret.

Excommunications are reserved, not the absolution itself. Being excommunicated though prevents one from receiving the sacraments.
